# C# Excel Interop Pivot Table Refresh COMException: 'Reference isn't valid.'

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pivot-table, interop

The line of code

xlSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh();

returns this exception

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Reference isn't valid.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you encountered with the pivot table in Excel is a common one, and it’s rooted in the way Excel handles data sources for pivot tables. To understand this, we need to delve into the inner workings of Excel and its data management system.

Excel is a powerful tool that allows users to manipulate and analyze large amounts of data. One of the key features of Excel is its ability to create pivot tables. A pivot table is a data summarization tool used in spreadsheet programs like Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets. Pivot tables are used to summarize, sort, reorganize, group, count, total or average data stored in a table. It allows its users to transform columns into rows and rows into columns. It allows grouping by any data field.

Pivot tables are highly flexible and can be quickly adjusted depending on how you need to analyze your data. They allow you to look at your data in a wide variety of ways, depending on your needs.

When creating a pivot table, Excel requires a data source. This data source can be a range of cells in a worksheet or an Excel table. In your case, you initially used an Excel table named “Table2” as the data source for your pivot table.

Excel tables are a way of grouping a range of cells into a single entity that you can refer to in formulas or use as a source for pivot tables. When you create an Excel table, Excel assigns it a name (“Table1”, “Table2”, etc.), and you can use this name when creating formulas or setting up data sources for pivot tables.

However, there’s a catch: when you use an Excel table as the data source for a pivot table, Excel doesn’t just look at the current state of the table. It also keeps track of the table’s structure and any changes made to it. This means that if you add or remove columns from the table, or if you change the order of the columns, Excel will update the pivot table accordingly.

This is usually a good thing because it means your pivot table will always reflect the current state of your data. But it can also lead to problems if you make changes to your table without realizing that it’s being used as a data source for a pivot table.

In your case, it seems that something about “Table2” changed which made it an invalid data source for your pivot table. This could have been caused by several things:

The structure of “Table2” changed: If you added or removed columns from “Table2”, or if you changed the order of the columns, this could have made “Table2” an invalid data source for your pivot table.
“Table2” was deleted: If you deleted “Table2”, this would certainly make it an invalid data source for your pivot table.
The name of “Table2” changed: If you renamed “Table2” to something else, this would make “Table2” an invalid data source for your pivot table because Excel would no longer be able to find it.
When you encountered the error message .COMException: 'Reference isn't valid.', this was Excel’s way of telling you that it couldn’t find or use “Table2” as a data source for your pivot table.

To fix this issue, you changed the data source from “Table2” to a range of cells. This is a valid solution because ranges of cells are more static than Excel tables: they don’t change unless you explicitly change them. By using a range of cells as your data source, you’re telling Excel exactly where to find the data for your pivot table, and this won’t change unless you change it yourself.

In conclusion, while Excel tables can be powerful tools for managing and analyzing data, they can also lead to unexpected issues when used as data sources for pivot tables due to their dynamic nature. It’s important to keep track of all changes made to an Excel table when it’s being used as a data source for a pivot table and to update the pivot table accordingly if necessary.

I hope this explanation helps clarify what happened in your case! Remember: understanding how Excel manages data sources is key to avoiding issues like this in the future.